# Pagination did not work on the first page. The current path, &vacancy=2, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django

I am implementing search with pagination in Django.
When I clicked Next pagination button, received error:

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/&vacancy%3D2

[image]

Also, pagination works after search (e.g. I searched something, then clicked pagination and it works)

I think that problem with views.py an urls.py
How can I solve the problem?

**models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    about = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Vacancy(models.Model):
    company_key = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    salary = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='40.000')
    text = models.TextField(default="The text about vacancy")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Москва')
    date_str = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='12 сентября')

    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    CHOICES = [
        ('ALL', 'ALL'),
        ('IT', 'IT'),
        ('FINANCE', 'FINANCE'),
        ('OTHER', 'OTHER'),
    ]
    department = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=CHOICES,
        default='ALL',
    )

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='vacancy_list'),
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
    path('vacancy/<int:pk>/', views.vacancy_detail, name='vacancy_detail'),

    path('accounts/login/', BBLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('accounts/profile/', profile, name='profile'),
    path('accounts/logout/', BBLogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    ...
```

**views.py**

```
class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Vacancy
    template_name = 'vacancy_list/vacancy_list.html'
    paginate_by = 5
    page_kwarg = 'vacancy'
    context_object_name = 'vacancies'


def vacancy_detail(request, pk):
    vacancy = get_object_or_404(Vacancy, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'vacancy_list/vacancy_detail.html', {'vacancy': vacancy})


class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Vacancy
    template_name = 'vacancy_list/search_results.html'
    paginate_by = 5
    page_kwarg = 'vacancy'
    context_object_name = 'vacancies'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        # added param
        context['query2'] = self.request.GET.get('q2')
        return context

    def get_queryset(self): # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        query2 = self.request.GET.get('q2')
        object_list = Vacancy.objects.filter(
             Q(title__icontains=query) and Q(department__icontains=query2)
        )
        return object_list
```

**vacancy_list.html**

```
{% block content %}

<div class="container col-md-8" style="margin:20px;">
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px; font-size: 2rem; padding-left: 0px;">
        <form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                     <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                    <select name="q2" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                        <option>ALL</option>
                        <option>IT</option>
                        <option>Finance</option>
                        <option>Other</option>
                    </select>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-12" style="padding-left: 0px;">

                     <button  class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


    {% for vacancy in vacancies %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h1><a href="{% url 'vacancy_detail' pk=vacancy.pk %}">{{vacancy.title}}</a></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                    <p> {{ vacancy.salary}} </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" style="white-space:normal">
            <p class="text-secondary">{{vacancy.company_key.name}}</p>
            <p> Описание вакансии: Компания Sixhands, занимающаяся разработкой мобильных приложений и веб-порталов в Санкт-Петербурге, ищет Backend-разработчика для создания серверной части мобильных приложений.
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <p>{{vacancy.city}} </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                    <p> {{vacancy.date_str }} </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>



    </div>
    {% endfor %}


    <!-- Paginator -->
    <div class="container" style="font-size: 2rem;">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ request.get_full_path }}?vacancy={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="page-item disabled">
                <span class="page-link">Previous</span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        <li class="page-item disabled">
                <span class="page-link">Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}</span>
        </li>
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
           <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ request.get_full_path }}?vacancy={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
        {% else %}
           <li class="page-item disabled">
              <span class="page-link">Next</span>
           </li>
        {% endif %}

    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- wrapper end -->

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query string starts with `?` after the URL path, appended.

As you have `/&vacancy=2`, it is being treated as a (or part) regular URL path, so being matched with the URLs in the `urlpatterns`. As there is no such URL, you're getting 404.

So replace `&` with `?`.

You would need `&` as the separator when you have multiple query stings e.g. `/spam/egg/?page=2&foo=bar`.

---

**Edit:**

To prevent the previous querysring being kept, use `request.path` (returns current path without query string) instead of `request.get_full_path()` (returns current path with query string) in the template:

```
href="{{ request.path }}
```

Comment: Thank you,
but when I clicked two times, received error (wrong url) **http://127.0.0.1:8001/?vacancy=2?vacancy=3**

Comment: @alcoder Check your template `vacancy_list/vacancy_list.html` and see how you are generating the paginated URL. It seems you're preserving the querystings (e.g. by referring the current URL with querystrings), drop them, only use the URL path.